# aligning a buttonbox in a gtk headerbar in gtk3.16

Tags: gtk, gnome, vala

I have the following code ;

```
    var window = new Gtk.ApplicationWindow (this);
    var headerbar = new Gtk.HeaderBar ();
    // headerbar.set_title("HeaderBar");
    headerbar.set_show_close_button(true);
    headerbar.set_vexpand(false);

    var buttonbox = new Gtk.ButtonBox(Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
    buttonbox.set_spacing(0);
    //Center buttonbox in headerbar
    buttonbox.halign = Gtk.Align.END;
    // buttonbox.
    // var menu_button = new Gtk.MenuButton();

    var add_button = new Gtk.Button.with_label("Add");

    var new_button = new Gtk.Button.with_label("New");
    buttonbox.add(new_button);
    var podcasts_button = new Gtk.Button.with_label("Podcasts");
    buttonbox.add(podcasts_button);
    var starred_button = new Gtk.Button.with_label("Starred");
    buttonbox.add(starred_button);

    headerbar.add(add_button);
    headerbar.add(buttonbox);

    // headerbar.add(menu_button);
    // headerbar.add(new_button);
    // headerbar.add(podcasts_button);
    // headerbar.add(starred_button);

    window.set_titlebar (headerbar);
    window.set_default_size (500, 400);
    window.show_all ();
```

I want to center the buttonbox in the headerbar. Apparently Gtk.Alignment is deprecated, so I have to use something like halign, valign but i have failed to see results

Comment: Did you try making the button box the headerbar's title widget?

Comment: how so? how do you do that

Comment: With `GtkHeaderBar.set_custom_title()`.